# PhpStorm debugging - server variable not showing in terminal

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm v9.0.

When I put break point in my CodeIgniter's `application/config.php` file to check `$_SERVER` variables, it is not showing 'HTTP_HOST', 'REMOTE_ADDR' , 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' in `$_SERVER` array.

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "not showing in terminal" ? 2) How do you debug -- are you debugging CLI script or web app via browser?

Comment: I mean in, it is not showing in debugger window, as you can seen in screen shot there is $_SERVER = array[71], so in this $_SERVER array, there is no server variable and hence I am getting "undefined index HTTP_HOST" in debugger, while the is printing in browser window.

Comment: Based on your screenshot you are debugging a CLI script. In CLI environment these "server variables" are indeed missing as they provided by web server only. Solution -- debug it via browser (so that script gets executed in web server context) and not as CLI script. Check some manuals (you seems to be new to PhpStorm and do not know the difference between different Run/Debug Configurations): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: okay thank you @LazyOne, will it give error in terms of php warnings in CLI? like I am getting now for undefined index.

Comment: It depends on your [PHP configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting). By default (both production and development .ini file templates) PHP will issue warnings when accessing non-existing index in array.